# Send data from applet to server on vaadin

Tags: java, applet, vaadin

I want to sent authorized data from applet to server using vaadin. If I understand right I have to use method like in [Screenshot addon](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/88), but i don't understand where in its code developer creates http connection.
I try to use `httpUrlconnection`, but I have fail with probably create connection.

Glassfish says:

```
SEVERE:   java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/CheckResponse/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
```

code:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:8080/CheckResponse/").openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to pass data via POST-GET method with the authentication credentials (or valid authentication) to vaadin web application from java applet.

I haven't managed applets, but if you want to do it from java (I think the only additional thing you will need is to include the apache-commons library in your build path or lib WEB-INF directory to make it work) you must do an HTTP GET/POST request from the java applet to your vaadin web application. Example given:

```
    /* FROM JAVA APPLET EXECUTE JSON GET */

    public static String getJson(String parameter) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        String url = "http://somedomain.com/VaadinApp?parameter=";

        String resp="";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + parameter); // here you put the entire URL with the GET parameters

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

// from here is postprocessing to handle the response, in my case JSON

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new   InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
    }



// if defined, this will return the response of the vaadin application, for this example no response is given from the server
        return sb.toString();
}
```

Then, in your vaadin application, you can process the GET/POST parameters via Vaadin Request, in this case, from your main UI:

```
public class VaadinApp extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = VaadinApp.class)

    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

     VistaPrincipal vp;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
         final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

         VistaPrincipal vp = null;

         vp = new VistaPrincipal();

         if(request.getParameter("parameter") != null) {
             Notification.show("Success");
         // show the parameter in GET request
             System.out.println("parameter:" + request.getParameter("parameter"));
        }

        layout.addComponent(vp);
        layout.setComponentAlignment(vp, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
        layout.setMargin(false);
        setContent(layout);

    }

}
```

The HttpRequest can be made in lots of ways, but be careful when sending parameters via GET because, they are shown in the URL. You can use POST instead, but it's still unsecure because the petition can be read by a "man in the middle", so you must at least encrypt it to prevent some kind of injection.